# Multidimensional Array Object allocation

Tags: javascript, object, multidimensional-array

So far, I'm trying to create a 2-Dimensional JSON array to hold a series of shapes inside a series of 'frames'. So far I thought I had it, but I can only push shapes to `frame[0]`; as soon as I pass it `frame[1]` I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shape' of undefined`.

Why can't my browser recognise `frame[1]` as a potential next storage area for the `frame` array? Is it something to do with how I've initialised the JSON Array?

Relevant code so far:

```
function Obj(type, x, y, w, h, r) {
"use strict";
this.type = type || null; //rect, crcl, line, text
this.x = x || null;
this.y = y || null;
this.w = w || null; //used for rect, line
this.h = h || null; //used for rect, line
this.r = r || null; //used only for crcl
}
var keyframes = {
    'frame': [{
        'shape': []
    }]
};

var shape1 = new Obj('rect', 20, 20, 20, 20, 0);
var shape2 = new Obj('crcl', 20, 20, 0, 0, 20);

keyframes.frame[0].shape.push(shape1);
keyframes.frame[1].shape.push(shape2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does recognize `frame[1]` as a *potential* place to put something, but you haven't put anything there.  Your code expects `frame[1]` to be a reference to an object but you only initialize the first element that way.

```
keyframes.frame[1] = { shape: [] };
```

will initialize the next element. Without that initialization, `keyframes.frame[1]` is `undefined`.

Comment: Perfect, now I just need to remember to initialise the next frame each time one is created. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

PROBLEM:

Your initialization of keyframes is as follows:

- an object
- contains a 1 element array 'frame'
- 'frame' contains an object

You CANNOT access keyframes.frame[1] because it does not exist (frame is a 1 element array so ONLY keyframes.frame[0] is valid)

SOLUTION:

- Create the keyframes.frame[1] element

  - keyframes.frame.push({shape: []});       //now keyframes.frame[1] exists
- push shape 2 to the object added above as you attempted before

  - keyframes.frame[1].shape.push(shape2);       //this should now be valid